# How do I prevent Approve-Reject-Reassign dialog from showing?

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I have an interesting requirement. How do I prevent Approve-Reject-Reassign Dialog box from showing when I need to approve a file. Instead, I have a different criterion for determining the document's approval.  If the check-in comments does not contain the word "Reject", then the request is considered approved.

If check-in comment contains "Reject" then send Rejection email to document author and stop workflow.  Otherwise, create task and send notify to next approver. I am using SharePoint Designer 2010.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this SharePoint Designer.
I assume you have SPD Approval workflow set on your item.

```
Start Approval process on Current Item with Head
```

Click on Approval

then
Change Behaviour of Single Task

then
under When a task completes

Modify this step to store check in comment.

you can read Current tasks comments using this action

```
Set Variable: vCheckinComment to [%Current Task:Comments%]
```

use below action in Main Worklfow.

```
If Variable: vCheckinComment contains Reject

Set content approval status to Rejected with Variable: CompletionReason

Else

vCheckinComment does not contains Reject

Set content approval status to Approved with Variable: CompletionReason
```

Please find my revised reply.

You dont need this much Complexity but rather follow below steps.

Go to main Workflow.

```
Start Collect Signature Workflow task process with Parameter:Signers
```

Then below that

```
Set Variable: vCheckinComment to Current Item:Check In Comment
```

Then Below that
use below action in Main Worklfow.

```
If Variable: vCheckinComment contains Reject

Set content approval status to Rejected with Variable: CompletionReason

Else

vCheckinComment does not contains Reject

Set content approval status to Approved with Variable: CompletionReason
```

So, Your Workflow will look like.

```
Start Collect Signature Workflow task process with Parameter:Signers

Set Variable: vCheckinComment to Current Item:Check In Comment

If Variable: vCheckinComment contains Reject

Set content approval status to Rejected with Variable: CompletionReason

Else

vCheckinComment does not contains Reject

Set content approval status to Approved with Variable: CompletionReason
```

Note: I don't have Collect Signature workflow enabled,but the steps should be the same.
Mine steps are for Approval Workflow.
Let me know, if you are not clear.

Comment: Do you mean add it to the "When the Item Is Changed" step within "When the Task Process Is Running" Step in Overall Tasks? Just want to clarify where the Main Workflow is.

Comment: No, Do you have Approval Workflow defined in SPD?

Comment: Click Workflows in Navigation under SPD.
Then click on your Workflow name.
Then Click on Edit Workflow- this is your main workflow.
in other words, where you have written your Approval Process Action- is your main workflow.

Comment: Yes, I do. I have a reusable workflow "rwf_Routing".

Comment: O I C. In the Notification Engine Step. I'll let you know how it goes. It is difficult to know where to add custom code because there are 3 different behaviors. I am a VS.NET user but can't use for this project.

Comment: The status remains "Not started" and the outcome is blank. It seems that events are only fired when you hit Approve or Reject in the dialog box which I don't want.

Comment: Please post your workflow steps, it will help in understanding your logic.

Comment: http://rlun0nu2d5.site.aplus.net/code/SPDWorkflow.html

Comment: My goal is to make this work with non-MS documents

Comment: I appreciate your help. Is there other information that you need?

Comment: I have changed my reply, please take a look.

Comment: I will try this again.